# Allowed "out" parameter types in a COM automation interface

Tags: com, vbscript, automation

I'm implementing COM automation (dual interface) for an application. The automation interface will be called from VBScript. I'm not quite clear on what types are allowed for the method's arguments. I do know that basically values have to fit in a `VARIANT`, but does that mean every parameter of type `int` must be passed through a `VARIANT`, or can one pass `int` directly?

For example, two methods I have in my MIDL file are:

```
HRESULT SetDate([in] int Year, [in] int Month, [in] int Day);
HRESULT GetDate([out] int* pYear, [out] int* pMonth, [out] int* pDay);
```

Calling `SetDate` from VBScript works. Calling `GetDate` as shown fails, which is to say that in the implementation, which is in C++, `ITypeInfo::Invoke` returns a code indicating a type error.

I've observed that if I use a `VARIANT` instead of an `int`, as shown below, it works.

```
HRESULT GetDate([out] VARIANT* pYear, [out] VARIANT* pMonth, [out] VARIANT* pDay);
```

So is `int` not allowed for parameters (because of the dual interface), or must I be doing something else wrong? If `int` is not allowed, why does `SetDate` work - is there a difference between `in` and `out` parameters in this respect?

Furthermore, this pair of methods works, although both use `int`:

```
[propget] HRESULT System([out, retval] int* pSystem);
[propput] HRESULT System([in] int System);
```

How come - are the rules for the allowed parameter types different for a property, or when the parameter is declared as `retval`?

I can't quite make sense of it all - would be grateful if anyone can clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, when you call the interface via `IDispatch`, all the parameters are always passed as `VARIANT`s. Yet, your implementation potentially uses other types. How is the gap bridged?

ATL (assuming that's what you're using) will implement `Invoke` for you, with code that converts arguments from `VARIANT`s to the proper types used by your method signature before forwarding the call to the actual method.

Here are the rules:

- `[in]` parameters can be just about any type that fits in a `VARIANT`, as you discovered. ATL (or whatever library you're using) will take care of translating parameters for you.
- `[in, out]` parameters must be `VARIANT*`. If you use anything else, either the call won't work or the return value will be lost (I don't remember which way it goes; you indicated you had a run-time error for this situation). Upon your method returning, ATL will convert the argument into an appropriate `VARIANT` so that VBScript (or whatever `IDispatch` client made the call) can get a hold of the output value.
- `[retval, out]` are a special case. You can use a pointer to whatever type you choose, and ATL will take care of it. I presume that what makes this possible is that the return value is provided back outside of the `DISPPARAMS` mechanism.
- `[out]`... just don't. They don't work - VBScript cannot use `[out]` parameters correctly. Mind you, they will "work" in that the method will execute without errors, but VBScript cannot distinguish between `[out]` and `[in, out]`, which means that VBScript expects your method to release whatever value was on the parameter when you received it. If you use `[out]`, whatever the client code placed on the parameter before making the method call will be leaked permanently.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not using ATL, just plain C++. If I change [out] to [out, ref], should that work?

Comment: Are you really implementing your own `Invoke`? That's a significant detail; you should add that to the question. In principle, you can write an implementation of `Invoke` that takes the vbscript-suplied `VARIANT` and converts it into a `int*` for your method (if it can, or return an error if not). Your Invoke would then be responsible to take the returning value of the parameter and stuff it back on the argument provided by the scripting client (if it can, or discard it if not). It's a non-trivial amount of work - the client can pass you anything, and you need to be ready for it.

Comment: Note: an earlier version of my post used `[ref]` when I meant to say `[in, out]` - a silly slip-up.

Comment: @Dabbler, using [out, ref] just declares that the return value cannot be null. It also doesn't change anthing because VBScript doesn't know about it. Remember that VBScript cannot see your type library; it only sees an IDispatch COM pointer. For VBScript it's all about "a list of VARIANTs goes in". `Invoke` has to bridge the gap between those VARIANTs and the actual method parameters. If one of the parameters in the call happens to be a named variable, VBScript will provide a `VT_BYREF` VARIANT, and that signals IDispatch to also update the VARIANT with a new value if necessary.

Comment: Very interesting - I have never dug into how ATL implements Invoke before, but you "made me look". I didn't realize that the heart of the implementation was supplied by COM-supplied APIs that parse the type library (`ITypeInfo::Invoke` as provided by a loaded Type Library) - probably the same API's you are calling. Then the information in my post applies to that standard implementation. You can still provide your own Invoke as I mentioned, but that would be most likely overkill.

Comment: Yes, I implement Invoke myself by calling LoadTypeLib and GetTypeInfoOfGuid, and then I call Invoke the type info pointer, passing through the arguments I recieved. If I remember correctly, I got this out of Dale Rogerson's book Inside COM.

Comment: @Dabbler, that's what I suspected you meant. The constraints I mentioned in my response apply to the Invoke that you get from GetTypeInfoOfGuid(). Your only other alternative would be to ignore the system-supplied `Invoke` and fully implement your own `Invoke`, completely by hand. Please note that I had originally said "[ref]" when I really meant "[in, out]".

Answer (score 2):

Types you are going to have less troubles with are listed on top of `VT_xxx` enumeration in Windows SDK:

```
enum VARENUM
    {   VT_EMPTY    = 0,
    VT_NULL = 1,
    VT_I2   = 2,
    VT_I4   = 3,
    VT_R4   = 4,
    VT_R8   = 5,
    VT_CY   = 6,
    VT_DATE = 7,
    VT_BSTR = 8,
    VT_DISPATCH = 9,
    VT_ERROR    = 10,
    VT_BOOL = 11,
    VT_VARIANT  = 12,
    VT_UNKNOWN  = 13,
    VT_DECIMAL  = 14,
    VT_I1   = 16,
    VT_UI1  = 17,
```

You don't see `INT` there, do you? `LONG` instead (which is `VT_I4`) is going to work just fine and be supported nice everywhere.

For scripting environment you are good to go with `VARIANT`s and if this makes your life easier on C++ side - with simple types mentioned above. If you need an array, `VARIANT` is a good holder for them as well.

A nice table there also hints about compatibility of types:

```
/*
 * VARENUM usage key,
 *
 * * [V] - may appear in a VARIANT
 * * [T] - may appear in a TYPEDESC
 * * [P] - may appear in an OLE property set
 * * [S] - may appear in a Safe Array
 *
 *
 *  VT_EMPTY            [V]   [P]     nothing
 *  VT_NULL             [V]   [P]     SQL style Null
 *  VT_I2               [V][T][P][S]  2 byte signed int
 *  VT_I4               [V][T][P][S]  4 byte signed int
 *  VT_R4               [V][T][P][S]  4 byte real
 *  VT_R8               [V][T][P][S]  8 byte real
 *  VT_CY               [V][T][P][S]  currency
 *  VT_DATE             [V][T][P][S]  date
 *  VT_BSTR             [V][T][P][S]  OLE Automation string
 *  VT_DISPATCH         [V][T]   [S]  IDispatch *
 *  VT_ERROR            [V][T][P][S]  SCODE
 *  VT_BOOL             [V][T][P][S]  True=-1, False=0
 *  VT_VARIANT          [V][T][P][S]  VARIANT *
 *  VT_UNKNOWN          [V][T]   [S]  IUnknown *
 *  VT_DECIMAL          [V][T]   [S]  16 byte fixed point
 *  VT_RECORD           [V]   [P][S]  user defined type
 *  VT_I1               [V][T][P][s]  signed char
 *  VT_UI1              [V][T][P][S]  unsigned char
 *  VT_UI2              [V][T][P][S]  unsigned short
 *  VT_UI4              [V][T][P][S]  unsigned long
 *  VT_I8                  [T][P]     signed 64-bit int
 *  VT_UI8                 [T][P]     unsigned 64-bit int
 *  VT_INT              [V][T][P][S]  signed machine int
 *  VT_UINT             [V][T]   [S]  unsigned machine int
 *  VT_INT_PTR             [T]        signed machine register size width
 *  VT_UINT_PTR            [T]        unsigned machine register size width
 *  VT_VOID                [T]        C style void
 *  VT_HRESULT             [T]        Standard return type
 *  VT_PTR                 [T]        pointer type
 *  VT_SAFEARRAY           [T]        (use VT_ARRAY in VARIANT)
 *  VT_CARRAY              [T]        C style array
 *  VT_USERDEFINED         [T]        user defined type
 *  VT_LPSTR               [T][P]     null terminated string
 *  VT_LPWSTR              [T][P]     wide null terminated string
 *  VT_FILETIME               [P]     FILETIME
 *  VT_BLOB                   [P]     Length prefixed bytes
 *  VT_STREAM                 [P]     Name of the stream follows
 *  VT_STORAGE                [P]     Name of the storage follows
 *  VT_STREAMED_OBJECT        [P]     Stream contains an object
 *  VT_STORED_OBJECT          [P]     Storage contains an object
 *  VT_VERSIONED_STREAM       [P]     Stream with a GUID version
 *  VT_BLOB_OBJECT            [P]     Blob contains an object 
 *  VT_CF                     [P]     Clipboard format
 *  VT_CLSID                  [P]     A Class ID
 *  VT_VECTOR                 [P]     simple counted array
 *  VT_ARRAY            [V]           SAFEARRAY*
 *  VT_BYREF            [V]           void* for local use
 *  VT_BSTR_BLOB                      Reserved for system use
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two different technologies involved in your question:

- COM Automation, wich evolves around the [IDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608.aspx) interface and friends (especially the restricted type system which doesn't need specific marshaling code because OLEAUT does the job automatically when it gets a TLB)
- VBScript, which is one specific COM Automation client.

out or in/out parameters that are not VARIANT are fine for COM automation in general, but not for VBScript, as VBScript basically only knows VARIANTs.

You will find the definitive explanation on Eric Lippert's blob here: [In, Out, In-Out, Make Up Your Mind Already](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/29/53117.aspx)