# Changing type of CComVariant variable doesn't work inside ATL method

Tags: c++, com, atl

I am trying to build an ATL COM class, which features the following method:

```
STDMETHODIMP CTestClass::TestMethod(VARIANT VarIn, VARIANT_BOOL* bRes)
{
    //VarIn is of type VT_INT

    CComVariant var(VarIn);
    var.ChangeType(VT_UI8); //doesn't work, HRESULT return value reports type mismatch
    ULONGLONG ullVal = var.ullVal; //wrong value is assigned
    *bRes = VARIANT_TRUE;
    return S_OK;
}
```

The problem is that the type of the `CComVariant` instance doesn't get changed **inside** the method. For example, if I pass an int-based value of 123 to the method as above, no type conversion to `VT_UI8` is performed.

However, if the `CComVariant` class is used in an independent function, changing the type via the `ChangeType()` method works flawlessly:

```
void Function()
{
    CComVariant var(123);
    var.ChangeType(VT_UI8); //ok
    ULONGLONG ullVal = var.ullVal; //correct value is assigned
}
```

Is there something I have overlooked? Thanks.

Comment: You are passing it by value.  So of course the caller's variant won't change.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't want to pass the variant back to the caller, that's why I've passed it by value. Instead, I would like to change the type of the `CComVariant` instance inside the ATL method. This would allow me to assign its value to a new ULONGLONG variable.

Comment: The Q lacks details. If you want to have converted value after return, then see comment above by Hans. If you have conversion failure, you have to mention input variant value and also check value returned by `ChangeType` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test code should have looked this way then:

```
CComVariant v;
v.vt = VT_INT;
v.intVal = 123;
const HRESULT n = v.ChangeType(VT_UI8); // 0x80020005 DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH Type mismatch.
```

`ChangeType` is backed by [`VariantChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221258%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, which...

> ...handles coercions between the fundamental types (including numeric-to-string and string-to-numeric coercions).

The problem is however that there are too many "fundamental" types defined and some are "more fundamental" than other. For example, `VT_I4` is better than `VT_INT`:

```
CComVariant v;
v.vt = VT_INT;
v.intVal = 123;
const HRESULT n1 = v.ChangeType(VT_UI8); // 0x80020005 DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH Type mismatch.
v.vt = VT_I4;
const HRESULT n2 = v.ChangeType(VT_UI8); // S_OK
ULONGLONG n = v.ullVal; // 123
```

That is, it appears that `VT_INT` is not accepted for API conversions. You will stay safer preferring types from the top of this list:

```
enum VARENUM
    {
        VT_EMPTY    = 0,
        VT_NULL = 1,
        VT_I2   = 2,
        VT_I4   = 3,
        VT_R4   = 4,
        VT_R8   = 5,
        VT_CY   = 6,
        VT_DATE = 7,
        VT_BSTR = 8,
        VT_DISPATCH = 9,
        VT_ERROR    = 10,
        VT_BOOL = 11,
        VT_VARIANT  = 12,
        VT_UNKNOWN  = 13,
        VT_DECIMAL  = 14,
        VT_I1   = 16,
        VT_UI1  = 17,
        VT_UI2  = 18,
        VT_UI4  = 19,
        VT_I8   = 20,
        VT_UI8  = 21,
        // *** Cut off line ***
        VT_INT  = 22,
        VT_UINT = 23,
```

Further reading:

- [Question regarding VT_INT in oleaut32](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2006-July/049584.html)
- [Allowed "out" parameter types in a COM automation interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512262/allowed-out-parameter-types-in-a-com-automation-interface/16518936#16518936)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Would this imply that I'd always have to resort to manual conversion routines when dealing with `VT_INT` and `VT_UINT` types?

Comment: You witness standard API not accepting `VT_INT`, so it should be a pretty good signal to avoid this type OR implement conversion on your own.